# Magento : Add static block to checkout cart

Tags: magento

I've been trying to work out how to add a static block to the checkout cart page before or after the coupon block.

Anything I've tried so far places the static block above or below the whole cart.

Below is the snippet from the local.xml

```
<reference name="content">
  <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
  <block type="cms/block"
    name="promotion_banner_checkout"
    before="coupon">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promotion_banner_checkout</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always edit the cart.phtml file in your own local version and add the block in there.

Just below `$this->getChildHtml('coupon');` add the following :

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('promotion_banner_checkout')->toHtml();`